# Is $RP^3$ a rational Homology Sphere

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is $RP^3$ a rational Homology Sphere? I always thought it wasnt, but it actually has with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients the same homology as the 3-sphere, doesn't it??

Comment: Well, carry out the computation and find out?

Comment: if i do the computations i would say it is. My problem is that it never get's mantioned as a rational homology sphere, which confuses me.

Comment: So what is your question?